# Plugin function not working

Tags: plugin, tags

I've created a plugin for a client that has two methods, the first of which is called from within the home template:

```
{exp:kapitex:get_products_carousel products="111, 113, 38"}
```

... which creates a carousel based on 3 entries, one of [Google's structured data types](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery), which you'll see if you [visit the website](https://www.kapitex.com/home), view source, and do a search for: "ItemList".

while the second *should* create a breadcrumb element, and is placed in the products template:

```
{exp:kapitex:get_products_breadcrumb product="{entry_id}"}
```

During testing, the `{entry_id}` sent the correct value, as did sending a raw value (which is to be expected). However, because I'm having problems with the ".htaccess" file with the local development machine, I wasn't able to test the method within the products template, and instead had to use the home template.

We've published the plugin on the client website and the `get_products_breadcrumb` appears not to get called.

I replaced the code with:

```
public function get_products_breadcrumb () {
    echo "XXXXXXXX";
}
```

... cleared the caches and still nothing, so it's not the code in the method.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `return "XXXXXXX";` Instead of "echo"?

Comment: When I tried `echo` before it spat out at the top of the page. However, I gave `return` a go and it made no difference.

Comment: `echo` will always add content to your page at the point at which the echo occurs. It won't inject that content into your template.